# How to set a title for Vizframe chart?

Tags: sapui5

I have tried to set a title for my vizFrame chart in SAP UI5, I have used title attribute in vizFrame control in my view, but it is not working and showing a default title as "Title of Chart". Could someone please help me how to set a title to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Set it in Javascript code (e.g. in 'onInit' of the controller):

   ```
   var oChart = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");    
   var asyncChartUpdate = function() {
       oChart.setVizProperties({
           title: {
               text: "Your title"
           }
       });
   };
   setTimeout(asyncChartUpdate, 0);
   ```

I did this asynchronously because it didn´t work for me synchronously.

2. Set it in XML view:

   ```
   <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" 
     vizProperties="{ title: {text : 'Your Title', visible : true}}"
     width="100%" vizType="column" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}">
   ```

Answer (score -1):

in Javascript it is work as synchronously.

code should be:

oChart.setVizProperties({
        title: {
            text: "Your title",
            visible : true
        }
    });